# What does it mean intuitively for a Taylor Series to be centered at a specific point?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I understand what a Taylor series is and how to find the Taylor series of a function. However I do not understand intuitively what it means to find a Taylor series for a specific function, centered at $x=a$ compared to $x=b.$ Can someone explain please?

Comment: A visual might help. If someone can build one that would be nice as I can't at the moment.

Comment: This is not so much for the OP but for folks doing a search and getting this post.  Matlab has a neat tool called Taylortool that will show you graphically how a change in 'a' affects your outcome.

Answer (score 6):

Intuitively, it means that you are anchoring a polynomial at a particular point in such a way that the polynomial agrees with the given function in value, first derivative, second derivative, and so on. Essentially, you are making a polynomial which looks just like the given function at that point. [Then Taylor's theorem guarantees that if continued to an infinite number of terms, the series will be the same as the given function.]

Comment: The Taylor series of an infinitely differentiable function at a point need not converge to the function itself. E.g., the series for $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ only converges on $(-1, 1)$, and the Taylor series for $x \mapsto e^{-1 / x^2}$ (and $0 \mapsto 0$) at $x = 0$ is the zero series, even though the function takes the value $0$ only at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

A Taylor series is an approximation of a function with 'easy' functions, namely polynomials. A major difference between a Taylor series centered at one point vs. another is the domain over which the series converges.

For example the Taylor series for $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ centered at $x = 0$ is

$$T_0(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...$$

This series converges on the interval $(-1,1)$. In other words, for all $x \in (-1,1), T_0(x) = f(x)$. However outside that interval, not so. For instance $f(-2) = 1/3$ but

$$T_0(-2) = 1 - 2 + 4 - 8 + 16 + ...$$ clearly doesn't converge.

Were we to write out the Taylor series of $f(x)$ centered at $x = -1$, we would have,

$$T_{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x+1}{4} + \frac{(x+1)^2}{8} + \frac{(x+1)^3}{16} + ...$$

This series, $T_{-1}$, converges instead on the interval $(-3,1)$. The expression for $T_{-1}(-2)$ does converge (check!).

Some Taylor series converge everywhere, such as the Taylor series for $e^x$ or $\sin x$.

Comment: I understand this. But the range seems to vary. Like for a=0, it is (-1,1) and for a=-1 it is (-3,1). Is there a way to tell what the range around 'a'  is for which the series converges?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in general, $F(x-a)$ slides the function $F(x)$ so that the new origin is located at $x=a$.

When we compute the Taylor series about zero, we're evaluating a power series in the form of $F(x) = \sum \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$.

When we compute the series about a point $a$, we're computing $F(x-a) = \sum\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k$, which is essentially "sliding" the polynomial over to the point $a$ while making sure that the coefficients of the sum match the behavior of $f(x)$ properly near $a$.

Comment: Ok I understand your explanation. However what if two different Taylor series' are found for the sin function centered at two different points. How do you know which one is better to approximate x at a given point.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly answered first by Nick and as reflected by others, Taylor's Polynomial (T) is a polynomial which looks just like the given function f(x) i.e. resembles/ approximates the real function as close as possible.

T about a point A is the value given by it when x=a.
Since the T is just an approximation polynomial to the real function f(x), there will be an error. This error indicates that how close is the polynomial (T) to the real function f(x).

f(x)=sin x at x=0 and x=pi/2 is 0 and 1 in true terms. Say by Using Taylors' polynomials to find sin x at x=0, pi/2, we can get 0 and 0.9 respectively. This means that the Taylor's polynomial does approximate a value but with an error of 0.1.

I hope this clears your question.

Answer (score 0):

centered at $a$ means the choice of the point $a$ in the formula 
$$\sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \, (x-a)^{n}$$

of the taylor series.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But whats the difference between finding the Taylor series for the sin function at x=0 compared to x=1.

Comment: you can imagine it as being most accurate around this point a.

Answer (score 0):

A Taylor series of a function $f(x)$, around $x=a$, when truncated at the $n$-th term, represent a polynomial of degree $n$ which - intuitively speaking- interpolates the function at the points $a, a+dx, a+2dx, \cdots, a+ndx$ with $dx \to 0$.
Then it is clear what is the difference between the (truncated) Taylor series around $x=a$ and $x=b$ : simply a polynomial interpolating $f(x)$ near $x=a$ and near $x=b$.